# Databricks Connect is not yet supported on the cluster with process isolation enabled

Tags: pyspark, azure-active-directory, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I'm using Azure Databricks (**6.5 Runtime**) and trying to hook it up to an IDE. However, in order to enable AAD credential passthrough in our cluster we need to set the following properties to true

```
spark.databricks.passthrough.enabled true
spark.databricks.pyspark.enableProcessIsolation true
```

But this causes databricks-connect test to fail with the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Databricks Connect is not yet supported on the cluster with process isolation enabled
```

Are there any workarounds for this? If not, then are there plans to support this use case anytime soon?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the below configuration is set to true.

```
 spark.databricks.libraryIsolation.processIsolation.enabled = true
```

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have similar issue.

Comment: no that doesn't work, when creds passthrough is enabled on HC cluster it enables processIsolation, the databricks-connect library is not yet compatiblie with that.